# Intern - Debugging out of memory exceptions

Tags: javascript, performance, unit-testing, out-of-memory, intern

We're currently running into the following error when running Intern test runner for our JS test suite.

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory`

This error occurs before any test information is passing. I suspect that some of our tests are leaking memory or doing some expensive operations. How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Node error rather than an Intern error. It indicates that the Node runtime has run out of memory.

A brute force fix would be to just allocate more memory to Node. You could try running node with the `--max_old_space_size` option, which affects the maximum amount of memory node can have allocated. The value is in megabytes; by default it's 512. Try something like `node --max_old_space_size=2048`.

A better fix would be to try to narrow down which suite (assuming it's a test suite) is allocating so much memory, and to modify the test or suite to mitigate the problem.

Comment: We're working on slimming down the test suites now. Thanks!